# Multiple Inner join blank result without error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi dev's i'm new with "advanced" SQL I've try alone but I dont understand how to have the good result.

I'll try to take information from 4 tables in the same DB.
The first table **items** only have id and name.
2 others tables take the id from **items** to extract data.
The last tables takes one data from items_buy for print another data.

Lastly I concat 2 column from 2 DB for having a full information.

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, items_buy.item_cost AS item_cost, items_sales.item_price AS item_price, CONCAT(trader.name, planet.name) AS name_point 
FROM ((((items
INNER JOIN items_buy ON items_buy.id = items.id)
INNER JOIN trader ON trader.id = items_buy.name_point)
INNER JOIN items_sales ON items_sales.id = items.id)
INNER JOIN planet ON planet.id = trader.planet)
WHERE items.id = 1;
```

I dont know how to make it work, she doesnt return an error in SQLyog or on my server.

[image: The output must be print in a simple html table screen here]

In order:
ID / NAMEITEM / PRICE / SELLINGPRICE / NAME from concat

If you need more, some test data:
https://pastebin.com/6Bs4kbN9

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would explain what you want.

Comment: If the issue is related to PHP please add the PHP code that reproduces it. (otherwise tag the DB version you are using, probably `sql-join`, and remove the PHP)

Comment: Are you certain that all the joined tables will _always_ contain each of the join fields?  If not, you should consider a `LEFT JOIN` instead

Comment: @MartinParkin At least in that specific request, yes

Comment: @ToqueySiGauses See my answer - in fact (based on your example data) this does not actually produce a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run your test data and run your script against it. As I suggested in my commment, the problem is with the `INNER JOIN` you are using.

I am not sure whether you are aware, but when using an `INNER JOIN`, if the joined table is NULL for the current row, then *nothing at all* will be returned.

If you modify your query to use a `LEFT JOIN`, you will see the results that are available regardless of whether the joined tables are NULL or otherwise:

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, items_buy.item_cost AS item_cost, items_sales.item_price AS item_price, CONCAT(trader.name, planet.name) AS name_point 
FROM ((((items
LEFT JOIN items_buy ON items_buy.id = items.id)
LEFT JOIN trader ON trader.id = items_buy.name_point)
LEFT JOIN items_sales ON items_sales.id = items.id)
LEFT JOIN planet ON planet.id = trader.planet)
WHERE items.id = 1;
```

This produces:

```
1   Agricium    24.45   25.6    NULL
1   Agricium    24.6    25.6    NULL
```

The problem in the case of your example is that the join to `trader` or `planet` has no result and therefore produces no output.

Comment: I must say thank's to you !

That mean my concat has fail if i've a NULL return... I'll need to fix it, but your help is just great.
I've a lot to learn about JOIN and SQL :'(